# Iterate over different CRTP Derived class methods

Tags: c++, crtp

In an example below I have a pretty typical CRTP example, two different derived classes that both have a method `bar`. The base class has a method `foo` which just forwards to some derived `bar` method

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
    }
};

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA> {
public:
    void bar() {
        ::std::cout << "A\n";
    }
};

class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB> {
public:
    void bar() {
        ::std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    DerivedA a;
    DerivedB b;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
}
```

It doesn't seem like I can have an array / vector / etc. of the base class because it would have to have a type along the lines of `Base<T>` where `T` is different

Is there some kind of convention without `virtual` for being able to iterate over different derived classes assuming they all have the same method (`bar` in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Boost.Variant.  For example:

```
typedef boost::variant<DerivedA, DerivedB> Derived;

struct BarCaller : public boost::static_visitor<void> {
    template <class T>
    void operator()(T& obj) {
        obj.bar();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Derived> vec{DerivedA(), DerivedB(), DerivedA()};

    BarCaller bar;
    for (Derived& obj : vec) {
        obj.apply_visitor(bar);
    }
}
```

This lets you store heterogeneous types in a vector or other STL container (by using a "discriminated union"), and lets you call a specific function on all of them regardless of their not having a common ancestor or any virtual methods.

Comment: Would you post a complete example? I have not used `boost::variant` before

Comment: I am guessing there would be no more `Base` and only `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` remain?

Comment: @asimes: OK, I slightly modified my answer to be a complete, runnable program if you combine it with your class definitions.  It makes no difference whether you have `Base` or not - my code works either way.

Comment: I will have to do some reading on `boost::variant` but thank you, it works just fine. I just need to understand what is going on under the hood

Answer (score 3):

> It doesn't seem like I can have an array / vector / etc. of the base class because it would have to have a type along the lines of `Base<T>` where `T` is different.

You can have a base class of `Base<T>` for all `T`, then, you can have a list/vector/array of pointers to the base class, if that works for you.

```
struct BaseOne
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual ~BaseOne() {}
};

template<typename Derived>
class Base : struct BaseOne {
public:
    void foo() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
    }
};
```

and then,

```
int main() {
    std::vector<BaseOne*> v {new DerivedA, new DerivedB };
    for ( auto item : v )
       item->bar();

    for ( auto item : v )
       delete item;
}
```

> Is there some kind of convention without `virtual` for being able to iterate over different derived classes assuming they all have the same method (`bar` in this case)?

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

As per now, variant has became part of the `C++17` standard and the solution to the problem can be solved by `std::variant` and `std::visit` as follows.

The template class in the example is `Interface<>` and use the CRTP idiom to *force* derived class to implement `helloImpl()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

template<typename Implementer>
struct Interface {
    void hello() const {
        static_cast<Implementer const *>(this)->helloImpl();
    }
};
```

A couple of class examples with different implementations of `helloImpl()`

```
struct Hello1 : public Interface<Hello1> {
    void helloImpl() const {
        std::cout << "Hello1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Hello2 : public Interface<Hello2> {
    void helloImpl() const {
        std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And here is how to use it to store data in a vector<> container and its traversal:

```
int main() {
    using var_t = std::variant<Hello1, Hello2>;
    std::vector<var_t> items{Hello1(), Hello1(), Hello2()};

    for(auto &item: items) {
        std::visit([](auto &&arg) {
            arg.hello();
        }, item);
    }
    return 0;
}
```